# Why doesn't Z-Index in IE render the way it's supposed to over a Flash Movie?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, z-index, css-position

I am working on a site with two absolutely positioned divs... the logo and the menu (navbar)

IE is burying them both, even after multiple tries of z-index manipulation. Why can't IE work as well as Firefox or even Opera for God's sake?

UPDATE.......

I forgot to mention that these divs are positioned over a flash movie. How could I possibly have left that out?!

Comment: Looks like they want us to give the parent div relative positioning and a z-index of 1. Still doesn't work for me though.

Comment: You may want to change the title of the question to include the fact that the issue is Flash-related.

Comment: This problem affects IE8 as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your flash movie is burying your other content you may have luck by adding an additional param element to your embedded object:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

For a longer answer you can see this [blog post about stacking windowed / flash content](http://blog.mediawhole.com/2008/11/stacking-windowed-elements-and-flash.html). Adobe has a [TechNote about this issue](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html), too.

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem. The Adobe link doesn't work anymore, though.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the note -- I updated the Adobe link with a working URL.

Answer (score 5):

IE has several well-documented Z-index bugs. It seems IE makes a new stacking context for positioned elements. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is also an issue in IE7.
Here's a link describing the problem:  http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug with IE6 (which I'm assuming you're using). Here's some description and some help: http://www.last-child.com/conflicting-z-index-in-ie6/