# iframe z index issue with pdf content

Tags: css, iframe, z-index

I have an iframe element that contains PDF document the element itself is benaeath a dropdown menu.

```
|Menu|
<iframe />
```

it is UI and I can not give you the exact explanation but I believe that you can imagine it. Everytime I click on the "Menu" dropdown a dropdown is generated. No matter that this dropdown has higher z-index attribute it always shows behind the iframe element. This happens in Chrome and IE. I don't know why but it works on Firefox. In other topics I saw that there is a solution if the content was a youtube video but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you aware that PDF files will only render on browsers which can read them? On browsers which *can't* read PDF files the file would end up being downloaded instead (think mobile phones, tablets and old browsers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [z-index and iframe issue - dropdown menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598450/z-index-and-iframe-issue-dropdown-menu)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly The PDF gets completely rendered for the browsers that I am aiming.

Comment: I made a quick test and I don't have a solution, but I did notice that it worked as desired in Chrome as well as FF. Just not in IE. By the way, IE does hide the frame border behind the popup. So it's not the iframe, it's the PDF itself that causes the problem.