# Flash Player z-index and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, z-index

Here is a [demo](http://cruisear.com/demo). Brown area and right column have to be prior. There is no problem in Firefox and Chrome. However, in IE flash player front all other elements. There is z-index both brown element and flash player and right column. How can i enable this page to seem same in all browsers?

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background:#000000;
    color:#fff;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.temizle{clear:both;}

/*****************  Player  *********************/
#flashobj {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}




#banner {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height:100px;
        width:85%;
        background: #88451c;
        z-index: 99;
}






/********************* Tag combination block on right side***********************/
 .FixedHeightContainer
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  font-family:"Arial",Georgia,Serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;

  z-index: 100;
}

.TContent
{
  color:#c11;
  height:95.8%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-image:url('http://cruisear.com/c/img/bg.png');
  color: #B7B7C7;
}

.checkbox{

}

.cbox:hover{
    background:#FCDC4C;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently z-index does not play well with flash. Hopefully this helps out. -> http://manisheriar.com/blog/flash_objects_and_z_index

Comment: Do you have any idea that how can i add it to flash object created by javascript, like my site?

Answer (score 2):

Have to add the wmode="opaque" (or wmode="transparent") attribute to the flash object itself. Then you can use z-index to set stacking order.

more info: [differences between using wmode="transparent", "opaque", or "window" for an embedded object on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886864/differences-between-using-wmode-transparent-opaque-or-window-for-an-embe)

```
<object wmode="opaque">
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me.

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

I found this solution at [Why doesn't Z-Index in IE render the way it's supposed to over a Flash Movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761402/why-doesnt-z-index-in-ie-render-the-way-its-supposed-to-over-a-flash-movie)

Comment: This seems to be the correct way, putting new param element inside of object element, rather than just adding attribute wmode="opaque" to the object element